# Using EntityFieldQuery with Address Field

Tags: 7, database, entities

I have a custom content type with a **postal_address** field provided by the module [addressfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield). postal_address fields are one field in the custom content type. This one field is comprised of many subfields like: country, name_line, and postal_code.

How can the core function **EntityFieldQuery** be used to retrieve nodes of my custom content type based on their postal code value (a subfield of the postal_address field)?

Specifically, I do not know what to put in the code below instead of the text: **what_goes_here**:

```
$query  =  new EntityFieldQuery();

$entities  =  $query->entityCondition( 'entity_type', 'node' )
  ->propertyCondition( 'status', 1)
  ->propertyCondition( 'type', 'consumer_store' )
  ->fieldCondition( 'what_goes_here', 'value', $postal_codes )
  ->execute();
```

Comment: There's nothing special about an addressfield, you can use an `EntityFieldQuery` as you would with any other field type. Where are you stuck exactly? Could you post the code you've tried with results/error messages etc?

Comment: I'm not sure it's that easy, because the value of of a postal_address field is an array of the subfields.

Comment: @JayHaase Do you allow addresses from multiple/any country?

Comment: @MPD: only from one country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although Addressfield can be extended, the standard columns like zip code are normal field columns and live in field storage (see [`addressfield_field_schema()`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!addressfield!addressfield.install/function/addressfield_field_schema/DC)).

In your case you want the `postal_code` column:

```
$query  =  new EntityFieldQuery();

$entities  =  $query->entityCondition( 'entity_type', 'node' )
  ->propertyCondition( 'status', 1)
  ->propertyCondition( 'type', 'consumer_store' )
  ->fieldCondition( 'field_postal_address', 'postal_code', $postal_codes )
  ->execute();
```

Comment: That works perfectly form me. Thank you for your patience!